# How to explain the simulation results of this op amp from LTspice?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

Here is what caused my confusion

Why the simulated output voltage is not 0 when the input amplitude at both terminals is 0.
When the input amplitude is 0(i.e.the input terminals are short-circuited), the output voltage is meant to be 0 in theory. However, LTspice simulation shows this is not so as shown below.
[image]

I know that op-amp maybe not be perfect during manufacture in reality, but does the simulation of LTspice also take into account these imperfections such that my results were produced?

Comment: The lousy old 741 opamp is 53 years old and should be buried. The simulation shows a fairly good one but a real one can have an output offset voltage of more than 66 times in the circuit.

Answer (score 4):

You want **ideal** results yet you simulate with a **non ideal** 741 opamp?

What you see is the DC offset of the opamp. This opamp has a small input current. This current flows through resistors R1 and R2 and that causes a voltage drop.

You don't have the same voltage drop at the + input of the opamp.

If you want **ideal / theoretical** results then only use **ideal** components, not (a model of) the 741.

When I want an ideal opamp, I use a Voltage-Controlled-Voltage-Source where I set the voltage gain to a high value like 1000. Then I might still get a small (few mV) offset here and there but the values will be close enough to what I need.

Comment: I see, but the 920uV result for offset voltage does not match exactly with that showed by the datasheet which is 1mV, why the difference?

Comment: *result for offset voltage does not match exactly* 1) It is **only** an 8% difference, explain why you need a higher accuracy that that. Explain **why** 8% error isn't good enough for you. 2) did you take into account the 80 nA input bias current of the opamp? 3) again, if you want **EXACT** results then don't use a 741, or any other model of a real opamp. Instead use a VCVS where you can set the gain yourself and which has 0 V (zero Volt) offset and ) also zero input bias current.

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough, I'm not a professional designer but just a starter learning op-amps, I'm asking with the simple aim of understanding the effects of input offset voltage and current and how LM741 works.

Comment: what I really want to know about now is just how the result 920uV was produced

Comment: maybe could you please direct me to some reference or guide that I can look into? That would be very helpful and I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I suggest you watch these videos by Dave from the EEVBlog: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FYHt5XviKc&list=PLvOlSehNtuHu2FviAaZaiyXwN41G4b1Lf  and then read "Opamps for everyone": https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Whether input offset voltage (and input offset current) is included or not (and what polarity, if any, they pick) is up to the creator of the model. It's not unusual to see some there- in this case the 'typical' value is +/-1mV from the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf).

If you look at a NS model, you can see that's what they have used:

> EOS 7 1 POLY(1) 16 49 1E-3 1
>
> *Input offset voltage.^

There is also a small amount of offset created by the unbalanced impedances at the inputs and the input bias currents. The *typical* input bias current of the LM741 at Tj=25°C is only 80nA, so that won't be very significant here.

Note that in reality the polarity could be opposite or the offset voltage could be as high as +/-6mV and the bias current as high as +/-500nA. All of which your design, if it's a good one, should accommodate.